# Write the given expression as an algebraic expression in $x$: $\tan(2 \cos^{−1} x)$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

OK I first assigned $\theta = \cos^{−1} x$

and so $\cos(\theta) = x$

drew a triangle where adj = $x$  hyp = $1$ and opp = $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ by pyth theorem.

Then $\tan(2\cos^{−1} x) = \tan(2\theta)$

and I used the double angle formula for tangent so

$\tan(2\theta) = \frac{2\tan(\theta)}{1-\tan^2(\theta)}$

Then used the triangle: $\tan(\theta) = \frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}$

but my answer is [image]

The computer states I am wrong. Am I setting the problem up wrong?

Comment: It looks like an incorrect substitution in what otherwise is fine.

Comment: There is a subtle point which in this case makes no difference. If $x$ is negative, then $\cos^{-1}x$ is between $\pi/2$ and $\pi$. So $\tan x$ is negative, meaning that taking the positive square root of $1-x^2$ gave the right value for $\tan x$. But sometimes one has to be careful about which square root one takes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set the problem up fine:

Let me retrace your work for you.

So you are correct with all your steps.

$$tan(\theta) = \frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x} $$

Now,

$$\tan{2\theta} = \frac{2*\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}}{1 - (\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x})^2}$$

$$ = \frac{\frac{2\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}}{1 - \frac{1-x^2}{x^2}}$$

$$= \frac{\frac{2\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}}{\frac{2x^2 - 1}{x^2}}$$

$$= \frac{2\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}*\frac{x^2}{2x^2 -1}$$

$$= \frac{2x\sqrt{1-x^2}}{2x^2 -1}$$

Comment: Great job. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Your setup is correct, but there seems to be an error in your algebra after you obtain $\tan \theta = \frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}.$  You should have $$\tan 2\theta = \frac{2 \sqrt{1-x^2}/x}{1 - (1-x^2)/x^2} = \frac{2x \sqrt{1-x^2}}{2x^2 - 1}.$$